# How to update Share count on Facebook after a site changed and sent a proper 301 redirect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I created a site, but it went throught a increase in structure, and a new folder level was added in url. The site sends a 301 redirect to point users to new url.

The problem is: The facebook button with the Share count is zero. It was counting 408.

I know I can point the counter to the URL to old page, but How to do it correctly using the 301 redirect? I don't want the old url anymore, just to update the count to the new url.

old url:
http://biblia.apelosurgentes.com.br/biblia/

( http 301 )

new url:
http://biblia.apelosurgentes.com.br/pt-br/biblia/

I already Fetched new scrape information on the old url using the facebook debug tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
But the count stills not getting transferred to new URL.

I see this as a facebook bug, because it is not following the 301 redirect rule. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/589414401234160/

Comment: No, that’s not a bug – the scraper _is_ following your redirect, and therefor sees the second URL as the “real” URL of the object. You need to keep your old URLs available, point the `og:url` meta tag of the new ones to those old ones, and have them serve the meta data to the FB scraper. Only clients that are not the FB scraper (a.k.a. human visitors) can be redirected to the new URL. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/#moving-urls

Comment: Thank you for commenting, but I see it as a bug. "keep old url": How if the domain name changes, for example? If moving the count to the new URL is not possible, I will give up and begin from zero.